# How can I make an Automator service run a shell script and display the output?

Tags: command-line, automator

I'm using Automator to run a shell script (ffmpeg transcode to h264) as a 'Service', so that I can just right click the high res .mov file and select the service. It works fine, but as it's ffmpeg it would be good to see the output in a Terminal window. Is there a way to see the output in real time?

Shouldn't make a difference, but here's the script just in case:

```
for f in "$@"
do
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -vf yadif -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 21 -preset slow -movflags faststart -c:a copy ${f%.*}_h264_yadif.mov
done
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This AppleScript will launch a Terminal window with the command you specified:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        set filesString to ""
        repeat with file_ in input
            set filesString to filesString & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_)
        end repeat
        do script "for f in" & filesString & "; do
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -c:v libx264 -vf yadif -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 21 -preset slow -movflags faststart -c:a copy ${f%.*}_h264_yadif.mov
done"
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Create a “Run AppleScript” action in Automator and paste it in there.

Comment: Works a like charm - thanks so much. I knew it would probably involve an AppleScript but was unsure of the voodoo to get the file path over to the shell script.

Answer (score 8):

Nice and clean solution is to **display message via Notification Center.**
Just execute the following terminal command in your script.

```
osascript -e 'display notification "All files converted" with title "ffmpeg converter"'
```

'osascript' command runs any AppleScript from terminal, 'display notification' pops up nice notification.

[image]

---

Also you can use 'display alert'. It has no limitation of message length and it's easy to add <kbd>OK</kbd> button to it.

```
osascript -e 'set alertResult to display alert "Bad news :( Error converting your video file." buttons {"OK"} as warning'
```

[image]

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/aslr_cmds.html) is Apple Script commands reference. Look for 'display notification' and 'display alert' for more information.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful for general things, but I'd really like to view ffmpeg's entire output. I also have a similar service that syncs a directory to my S3 backup via s3cmd. In both cases, the full output is sort of essential for handling errors properly...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution that I got working, which shows the command output once it's finished:

1. Pass the output of a *Run Shell Script* action to *Set Value of Variable*
2. Use that variable to, for example, display a notification.

[image]

For example, with the `test.py` Python script, all I'm doing is printing the arguments passed (“Running a script with …”), so when I run it, after finishing, it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an Automator action called "View Results" under utilities. It is exactly what I was looking for, showing me the output of a shell script.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that only works from within Automator. If that works for you, great! I thought you had a significant amount of text you wanted in a scrolling window.